# Save the multiple plot in loop in R to pdf

Tags: r

I have two different plots. I want to put them together, I use them to save in pdf. However, the pdf can not open. I am using the following simple template to save the figures in pdf, can you please help me with that? Thanks.

```
for(i in 1:4){

   par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
   # plot 1 
   layout(matrix(c(rep(1,6),rep(2,4)),nrow=2,ncol=5))

    plotModelFit(dataBlock,fit)
    plotMarginal(extract(fit,"beta[1]"),predictor="dataset age",col="blue")

    #plot 2
    plotModelFit(dataBlock,fit)
    plotMarginal(extract(fit,"beta[1]"),predictor="dataset age",col="blue")

    # save to pdf
    pdf(file=sprintf("/Users/test.pdf",responseVars[i]),width=10,height=6)
    dev.off()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need only one of `par(mfrow=c(2, 1))` and `layout(matrix(c(rep(1,6),rep(2,4)),nrow=2,ncol=5))`.
2. you need to place `pdf()` call before `par()` or `layout()`.
3. you need something like `sprintf("/Users/test-%s.pdf",responseVars[i])` for the file name.